# Netplan default route metric 0 is a big problem

Tags: networking, netplan

Hi I have set up a simple router using  Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64). It is a virtual machine. The objective is that all traffic arriving on the first network card(eth0) is sent via a second network card (eth1) to our firewall. I have added a route to netplan for this. The problem is netplan (apply or on server reboot )is creating a default route with a mertic of 0. As the firewall is on the same subnet all traffic is using the default route and going directly to the servers and not to the firewall.. Not ideal!!
I can get around this by deleting the default root (I have a reboot script that does this, not ideal but was functional untill I moved the virtual machine between hosts without rebooting and netplan recreated it!!) I need to find a better way to either stop the default route being created or setting its metric to more than 0.

I have configured netplan as:

```
network:
  Version: 2
  Ethernets:
       eth0:
           addresses:[x.x.x.94/26]
           gateway4: gwgwgwgw
           nameservers:
               addresses: [x,y]
       eth1:
           addresses:[y.y.y.y.62/26]
           nameservers:
               addresses: [w,x]
        routes: 
        - to: y.y.y.y.0/26
          via:  y.y.y.y.37
```

This gives route output as:

```
root@:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         blabla.         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
x.x.x.64        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
Y.Y.Y.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth1
Y.Y.Y.0        Y.Y.Y.37.s       255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth1
```

I need to stop "Y.Y.Y.0         0.0.0.0 " being created or set its metric so the route "Y.Y.Y.0        Y.Y.Y.37.s" is prefered.

I cannot find away to do this in the documentation. Please help
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a Y.Y.Y.0/26 route being treated as local to eth1, then you should not declare it as the netmask of your `address`.  You appear to need:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
       eth0:
           addresses: [x.x.x.94/26]
           gateway4: gwgwgwgw
           nameservers:
               addresses: [x,y]
      eth1:
           addresses:[y.y.y.y.62/32]
           nameservers:
               addresses: [w,x]
        routes:
        - to: y.y.y.y.0/26
          via:  y.y.y.y.37
          on-link: yes
```

Comment: This is sound advice, Thanks!  It will not allow me to adjust the default route but it may well solve my problem.

Comment: I tried that and it seems to solve the problem, The "on-link: true"  is the key .. thanks!